# Как поставить ожидание действия?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Вот меню:https://jsfiddle.net/b5uma4re/2/ Если на вкладке "О нас" несколько раз наводить и убирать указатель мыши, то подменю будет выезжать несколько раз. Как сделать чтобы подменю реагировало только если указатель находится 500 миллисекунд ? т. е. если указатель продержался 400 миллисекунд и убрался то подменю не появляется.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $('.w1').hover(
        function(){
        $(this).find('.q1').delay(500).slideToggle();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.q1').delay(500).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cont{
    font-size: 0;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.q1{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 165px;
    display: none;
}
.q1 li{
    border-top: 1px gray solid;
    display: block;
}
.w1{
    font-size: 16px;
    border-left: 1px black solid;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.w2{
    position: relative;
}
.w3{
    position: relative;
}
.q2, .q3{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 210px;
    display: none;
}
li:hover{
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cont">
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">Домой</a></li><!----------------------->
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">О нас +</a><!----------------------->
         <ul class="q1 fir"><li><a href="#">Наша история</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Как нас найти</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Час работы</a></li>
         </ul></li><!----------------------->
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">Наши товары +</a>
         <ul class="q1">
            <li class="w2"><a href="#">+ Штуковины</a>
                <ul class="q2">
                <li><a href="#">Простая штуковина</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Стандартная штуковина</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Продвинутая штуковина</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class="w2"><a href="#">+ Гаджеты</a>
                <ul class="q2">
                <li><a href="#">Простой гаджет</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Стандартный гаджет</a></li>
                <li class="w3"><a href="#">+ Продвинутый гаджет</a>
                    <ul class="q3">
                     <li><a href="#">Продвинутый гаджет A</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Продвинутый гаджет Б</a></li>   
                    </ul></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Машини времени</a></li> 
         </ul></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` ?

Comment: $(this).find('.q1').setTimeout(500).delay(500).slideToggle(); Так не работает

Comment: дак и не должно. setTimeout это обычная JS-функция, одним из параметров которой будет время через которое срабатывает, а второй - callback, который через это время запускается.

Comment: @teran Помогите применить к моему примеру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, вот так, используя метод [.stop()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) для [прекращения текущей анимации](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.w1').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.q1').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideDown();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.q1').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideUp();
        });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cont{
    font-size: 0;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.q1{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 165px;
    display: none;
}
.q1 li{
    border-top: 1px gray solid;
    display: block;
}
.w1{
    font-size: 16px;
    border-left: 1px black solid;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.w2{
    position: relative;
}
.w3{
    position: relative;
}
.q2, .q3{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 210px;
    display: none;
}
li:hover{
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cont">
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">Домой</a></li><!----------------------->
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">О нас +</a><!----------------------->
         <ul class="q1 fir"><li><a href="#">Наша история</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Как нас найти</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Час работы</a></li>
         </ul></li><!----------------------->
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">Наши товары +</a>
         <ul class="q1">
            <li class="w2"><a href="#">+ Штуковины</a>
                <ul class="q2">
                <li><a href="#">Простая штуковина</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Стандартная штуковина</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Продвинутая штуковина</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class="w2"><a href="#">+ Гаджеты</a>
                <ul class="q2">
                <li><a href="#">Простой гаджет</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Стандартный гаджет</a></li>
                <li class="w3"><a href="#">+ Продвинутый гаджет</a>
                    <ul class="q3">
                     <li><a href="#">Продвинутый гаджет A</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Продвинутый гаджет Б</a></li>   
                    </ul></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Машини времени</a></li> 
         </ul></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Остался один нюанс вот почти рабочий вариант:  https://jsfiddle.net/b5uma4re/8/ Осталось одно - если быстро наводить и убирать курсор подменю всё ровно реагирует, хотя должна реагировать только по удержанию курсора 500миллисекунд

Comment: @PeGaS вы уверены? ничего тут не показывается если навести и убрать.